# Как совершить проход цикла только один раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, python-2.x

Есть такой код:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for i in (lst):
    print('yes')
>yes
yes
yes
yes
```

В примере сверху, вместо списка там директория с большим количеством файлов, вместо print - другое действие.

Проблема в том, что мне нужно выполнить действие, в данном случае `print`, только один раз, первый!

Список, то есть свою директорию я менять не могу, кол-во файлов в ней останется неизменным, и цикл проходит по ним всем, но выполнить действие надо один раз, а выходит столько раз, сколько есть файлов в директории.

Я вижу только вариант добавлять все мои действия в список и затем брать оттуда первый элемент, но это выглядит как костыль. Хочется решения с вышеуказанным циклом.

Comment: Поставьте "другое действие" перед циклом

Comment: print ( lst[0] )

Comment: Неправильно....

Comment: @КириллВишняков, а по-моему, правильно! Сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать правильный ответ...

Comment: Зачем вам вообще цикл если тело цикла должно выполниться только один раз?

Comment: print ( lst[0] ) – чем эта строка поможет напечатать yes один раз?

Comment: `print('yes')` - напечатает `"yes"` ровно один раз... и никаких циклов... ;)

Comment: Это не ответ) меня интересует выполнение цикла один раз вне зависимостb от количества итерируемых элементов. Возможно, правильно это записать через прерывание (break)

Comment: [ "yes" for i, item in enumerate(lst) if i==0]

Comment: @КириллВишняков, повторю свой вопрос - зачем цикл, если выполнить действие нужно один раз?

Comment: В общем это классический пример [вопроса "Ошибка Молотка"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)  - опишите вашу изначальную проблему более широко. PS не надо забивать гвозди микроскопом... ;)

Comment: Ладно, весь вопрос будет слишком большим.

Answer (score 5):

При такой постановке вопроса, совершенно ясно, что цикл не нужен вообще.

Назначение циклов повторять набор инструкций много (больше одного) раз. Если какое-либо действие или набор действий нужно выполнить один раз - значит цикл вам не нужен.

Возможно вам нужен итератор и/или функция `next()` или написать функцию и передавать в нее итератор или список или другое решение, но, скорее всего, цикл здесь не нужен.

PS попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Можно же привести небольшой пример, который поможет понять проблему/задачу...

---

PPS правильный ответ на вопрос, в его текущей формулировке:

```
print('yes')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    if(index == 0):
         print('yes')
         break
```

Но это какой-то костыль, вы задачу неправильно поставили

Comment: `if` можно убрать. `index` и `enumerate` тоже.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(1):
    print('yes')
```

Цикл в одну итерацию, это сильно)))

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in (x for x in [len(lst)] if lst):
    print('yes')
```

Выполняется ровно один раз, если список `lst` не пустой.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
step = 0
for i in (lst):
    step +=1
    if step == 2:
        continue
    print('yes')
```

Кастомный/кастыльный (счётчик + `continue`) способ.

Но лучше подумать немного,амиго. Не нужно делать велосипед,когда есть мопед;)

Answer (score 0):

Иногда приходится писать цикл, который исполняется только один раз:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for i in lst:
    print('yes')
    break
```

Для списка в этом не много смысла, для `iterable` смысл появляется - это простейший способ проверить что `iterable` не пуст.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через `enumerate(lst)`. В этом случае первый `i = 0`, что эквивалентно `False`. В этом случае `if not i` делаем принт, а дальше цикл работает без принтов.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    print('yes') if not i else None
```

Еще вариант с триггером:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
printed = False
for v in lst:
    if not printed:
        printed = print('yes') or True
```

Ха, только сейчас заметил, что некропост)